# I recently had a mini-failure on a 2 ton hydraulic jack, How do I verify it is still safe to use, or service it?

Tags: hydraulic, stands, floor-jack, calibrate

I recently had a mini-failure on a 2-ton hydraulic jack. Whilst I was lowering the vehicle, it started to give way and sounded a bit rough on the way down.

It may also have been a case of a slightly over-opened valve, but I'm not sure.

Thankfully the original height setting used on the stands was only one notch, although I did try to take both sides up to 2 notches and on the second side, I seemed to run out of leverage to get me high enough to raise it to 2 notches on the stand.

**How do I either:**

a) verify the 2-ton floor-jack is still safe to use, or

b) service it to make sure it is?

Comment: What do you mean by started to give way? I don't understand what went wrong with it.

Comment: Well, when I opened the valve the lowering began but when I tried to tighten it again to try to control the lowering and slow it down, it didn't respond and it kept coming down rather quickly. On the way down it made a kind of grating sound.

Comment: That certainly concerning @Jim. Is this a trolley jack or a bottle jack?

Comment: I'd recommend just replacing the jack at this point.

Comment: How much does a replacement cost, and how much do you value your life?

Comment: trolley-jack, GdD

Comment: Jon Custer, I do value my life. And yes, more so than a trolley-jack, although I would have thought it's worth trying to learn from what actually happened. Preferably before I go and buy a new jack.

Answer (score 0):

I would not consider a Jack safe if it did not respond to closing the valve. I would replace the seals and test it on a vehicle that's safe to drop (without removing the wheels and not jacked too high)

Comment: What seals would those be, Madcow69?

Comment: @Jim Probably O-rings. Do you have a drawing or part list?